# Found class com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.naming.JndiLookupFacade, but interface was expected

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

I am getting the issue described up above when running integration tests.

The full error message follows:

```
error message="Found class com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.naming.JndiLookupFacade, 
but interface was expected" type="java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError">

java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: 
Found class com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.naming.JndiLookupFacade, but interface was expected at 
com.sap.cloud.extensibility.servlets.ForecastInboundInterfaceServletTest.beforeClass
(ForecastInboundInterfaceServletTest.java:39)
```

And the dependency tree:

```
--- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ anaplan-inbound-integration-tests ---
[INFO] com.sunstar:anaplan-inbound-integration-tests:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.sunstar:anaplan-inbound-application:jar:classes:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sap.cloud.s4hana.cloudplatform:scp-neo:jar:2.20.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sap.cloud.s4hana.cloudplatform:auditlog-scp-neo:jar:2.20.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.sap.cloud.s4hana.cloudplatform:core:jar:2.20.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.sap.cloud.s4hana.cloudplatform:auditlog:jar:2.20.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sap.cloud.s4hana.cloudplatform:caching:jar:2.20.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.sap.cloud.s4hana.cloudplatform:security:jar:2.20.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.sap.cloud.s4hana.cloudplatform:tenant:jar:2.20.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sap.cloud.s4hana.cloudplatform:core-scp-neo:jar:2.20.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sap.cloud.s4hana.cloudplatform:connectivity-scp-neo:jar:2.20.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.sap.cloud.s4hana.cloudplatform:connectivity:jar:2.20.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.sap.cloud.s4hana.frameworks:hystrix:jar:2.20.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- com.netflix.archaius:archaius-core:jar:0.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.netflix.hystrix:hystrix-core:jar:1.5.18:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- io.reactivex:rxjava:jar:1.3.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sap.cloud.s4hana.cloudplatform:security-scp-neo:jar:2.20.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sap.cloud.s4hana.cloudplatform:servlet:jar:2.20.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sap.cloud.s4hana.cloudplatform:tenant-scp-neo:jar:2.20.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sap.cloud.s4hana.cloudplatform:metering-scp-neo:jar:2.20.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.sap.cloud.s4hana.frameworks:hystrix-scp-neo:jar:2.20.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.sap.cloud.s4hana.cloudplatform:concurrency-scp-neo:jar:2.20.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sap.cloud.s4hana:s4hana-all:jar:2.20.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sap.cloud.s4hana:core:jar:2.20.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.sap.cloud.s4hana:fluent-result:jar:2.20.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sap.cloud.s4hana:connectivity:jar:2.20.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sap.cloud.s4hana:datamodel:jar:2.20.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.sap.cloud.s4hana.datamodel:bapi-api:jar:2.20.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.sap.cloud.s4hana.datamodel:odata-core:jar:2.20.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.sap.cloud.s4hana.datamodel:odata-api:jar:2.20.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sap.cloud.s4hana:soap:jar:2.20.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sap.cloud.s4hana:rfc:jar:2.20.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.sap.cloud.s4hana.quality:common:jar:2.20.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.sap.cloud.servicesdk:odatav2-connectivity:jar:1.32.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.sap.cloud.servicesdk:jacksonutil:jar:1.32.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:jar:3.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- ognl:ognl:jar:3.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.20.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.attoparser:attoparser:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.unbescape:unbescape:jar:1.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.modelmapper:modelmapper:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform:scp-neo:jar:3.11.0:test
[INFO] |  +- com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform:auditlog-scp-neo:jar:3.11.0:test
[INFO] |  +- com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform:caching:jar:3.11.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.github.ben-manes.caffeine:caffeine:jar:2.8.0:test
[INFO] |  +- com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform:cloudplatform-core-scp-neo:jar:3.11.0:test
[INFO] |  +- com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform:cloudplatform-connectivity-scp-neo:jar:3.11.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform:cloudplatform-connectivity-scp:jar:3.11.0:test
[INFO] |  +- com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform:security-scp-neo:jar:3.11.0:test
[INFO] |  +- com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform:servlet:jar:3.11.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform:tenant-scp-neo:jar:3.11.0:test
[INFO] |  \- com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform:metering-scp-neo:jar:3.11.0:test
[INFO] |     +- com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform:resilience:jar:3.11.0:test
[INFO] |     \- com.sap.cloud.sdk.frameworks:resilience4j:jar:3.11.0:test
[INFO] |        +- io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-circuitbreaker:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO] |        |  \- io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-core:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO] |        +- io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-bulkhead:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO] |        +- io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-timelimiter:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO] |        +- io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-cache:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO] |        |  \- javax.cache:cache-api:jar:1.1.0:test
[INFO] |        \- io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-retry:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO] +- com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana:s4hana-all:jar:3.11.0:test
[INFO] |  +- com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana:s4hana-core:jar:3.11.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel:fluent-result:jar:3.11.0:test
[INFO] |  +- com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana:s4hana-connectivity:jar:3.11.0:test
[INFO] |  +- com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel:odata-core:jar:3.11.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sap.cloud.servicesdk:odata-v2-lib:jar:1.32.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.sap.cloud.servicesdk:developer_license:jar:1.32.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jsoup:jsoup:jar:1.12.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-text:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.10.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.sap.cloud.sdk.quality:odata-querylistener:jar:3.11.0:test
[INFO] |  +- com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana:s4hana-api-odata:jar:3.11.0:test
[INFO] |  +- com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel:soap:jar:3.11.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-adb:jar:1.7.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-dom:jar:1.2.21:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.2.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |        \- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-transport-http:jar:1.7.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-kernel:jar:1.7.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api:jar:1.2.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-activation_1.1_spec:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.james:apache-mime4j-core:jar:0.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-impl:jar:1.2.21:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-ws-metadata_2.0_spec:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.neethi:neethi:jar:3.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.woden:woden-core:jar:1.0M10:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.axis2:axis2-transport-local:jar:1.7.9:runtime
[INFO] |  +- com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana:rfc:jar:3.11.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sap.cloud.sdk.quality:common:jar:3.11.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-csv:jar:1.7:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.json:json:jar:20180813:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sap.cloud.servicesdk:odatav2-connectivity-sdk3:jar:1.36.2:test
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.8.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.sap.cloud.servicesdk:jacksonutil-sdk3:jar:1.36.2:test
[INFO] |     \- com.sap.cloud.servicesdk.prov:api:jar:1.32.0:compile
[INFO] |        +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |        \- com.sap.cds:cds4j-api:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.sap.cloud.sdk.testutil:testutil-core:jar:3.11.0:test
[INFO] |  +- com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform:auditlog:jar:3.11.0:test
[INFO] |  +- com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform:cloudplatform-core:jar:3.11.0:test
[INFO] |  +- com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform:cloudplatform-connectivity:jar:3.11.0:test
[INFO] |  +- com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform:security:jar:3.11.0:test
[INFO] |  +- com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform:tenant:jar:3.11.0:test
[INFO] |  +- com.sap.cloud.sdk.testutil:testutil-resources:jar:3.11.0:test
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.vavr:vavr:jar:0.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.vavr:vavr-match:jar:0.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:27.0.1-jre:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.guava:failureaccess:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.guava:listenablefuture:jar:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:jar:1.17:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.9.9:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.23:test
[INFO] |  +- com.mikesamuel:json-sanitizer:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.3.4:test
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.12.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:2.22.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.8.21:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.8.21:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.6:test
[INFO] |  +- com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock:jar:2.19.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.4.17.v20190418:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.4.17.v20190418:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.4.17.v20190418:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:9.4.17.v20190418:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:9.4.17.v20190418:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:jar:9.4.17.v20190418:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:jar:9.4.17.v20190418:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.4.17.v20190418:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:jar:9.4.17.v20190418:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:jar:9.4.17.v20190418:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.5.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-legacy:jar:2.5.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:test
[INFO] |  |  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:jar:5.0.3:test
[INFO] |  |  +- com.flipkart.zjsonpatch:zjsonpatch:jar:0.4.4:test
[INFO] |  |  +- com.github.jknack:handlebars:jar:4.0.7:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:jar:4.7.1:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.github.jknack:handlebars-helpers:jar:4.0.7:test
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.10:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.26:test
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.26:test
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:jar:1.7.26:test
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- io.rest-assured:rest-assured:jar:4.0.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:jar:2.5.6:test
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-xml:jar:2.5.6:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.5.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:tagsoup:jar:1.2.1:test
[INFO] |  +- io.rest-assured:json-path:jar:3.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-json:jar:2.4.15:test
[INFO] |  |  \- io.rest-assured:rest-assured-common:jar:3.2.0:test
[INFO] |  \- io.rest-assured:xml-path:jar:4.0.0:test
[INFO] |     +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2.12:test
[INFO] |     +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-osgi:jar:2.2.10:test
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.sling:org.apache.sling.javax.activation:jar:0.1.0:test
[INFO] |        \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1.1:test
[INFO] +- org.apache.tomee:arquillian-tomee-embedded:jar:7.0.5:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomee:arquillian-openejb-transaction-provider:jar:7.0.5:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.extension:arquillian-transaction-impl-base:jar:1.0.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.extension:arquillian-transaction-api:jar:1.0.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.jboss.arquillian.extension:arquillian-transaction-spi:jar:1.0.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.test:arquillian-test-spi:jar:1.4.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.arquillian.core:arquillian-core-spi:jar:1.4.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  |     \- org.jboss.arquillian.core:arquillian-core-api:jar:1.4.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-spi:jar:1.4.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.config:arquillian-config-api:jar:1.4.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.config:arquillian-config-impl-base:jar:1.4.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.jboss.arquillian.config:arquillian-config-spi:jar:1.4.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-api:jar:1.2.6:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-test-spi:jar:1.4.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-test-api:jar:1.4.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.junit:arquillian-junit-container:jar:1.4.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.junit:arquillian-junit-core:jar:1.4.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.test:arquillian-test-api:jar:1.4.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.core:arquillian-core-impl-base:jar:1.4.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.test:arquillian-test-impl-base:jar:1.4.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-impl-base:jar:1.4.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-test-impl-base:jar:1.4.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-impl-base:jar:1.2.6:test
[INFO] |  |     \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-spi:jar:1.2.6:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.myfaces.core:myfaces-api:jar:2.2.12:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors:shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-javaee:jar:2.0.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors:shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-base:jar:2.0.0:test
[INFO] |  |     \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors:shrinkwrap-descriptors-spi:jar:2.0.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors:shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-javaee:jar:2.0.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors:shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-base:jar:2.0.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomee:javaee-api:jar:7.0-1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomee:arquillian-tomee-common:jar:7.0.5:test
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tomee:arquillian-common:jar:7.0.5:test
[INFO] |     \- org.codehaus.swizzle:swizzle-stream:jar:1.6.2:test
[INFO] +- org.apache.tomee:tomee-embedded:jar:7.0.5:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomee:tomee-catalina:jar:7.0.5:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomee:tomee-jdbc:jar:7.0.5:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomee:tomee-juli:jar:7.0.5:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomee:tomee-util:jar:7.0.5:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomee:javaee-api:jar:tomcat:7.0-1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-websocket-api:jar:8.5.32:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomee:tomee-myfaces:jar:7.0.5:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.openwebbeans:openwebbeans-jsf:jar:1.7.5:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.openwebbeans:openwebbeans-impl:jar:1.7.5:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.openwebbeans:openwebbeans-web:jar:1.7.5:test
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.openwebbeans:openwebbeans-el22:jar:1.7.5:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomee:openejb-core:jar:7.0.5:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomee:mbean-annotation-api:jar:7.0.5:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomee:openejb-jpa-integration:jar:7.0.5:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomee:openejb-api:jar:7.0.5:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomee:openejb-loader:jar:7.0.5:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomee:openejb-javaagent:jar:7.0.5:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomee:openejb-jee:jar:7.0.5:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomee:openejb-jee-accessors:jar:7.0.5:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.metatype.sxc:sxc-jaxb-core:jar:0.8:test
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.metatype.sxc:sxc-runtime:jar:0.8:test
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.activemq:activemq-ra:jar:5.14.5:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.activemq:activemq-kahadb-store:jar:5.14.5:test
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.apache.activemq.protobuf:activemq-protobuf:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.activemq:activemq-broker:jar:5.14.5:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.activemq:activemq-client:jar:5.14.5:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.fusesource.hawtbuf:hawtbuf:jar:1.11:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.activemq:activemq-openwire-legacy:jar:5.14.5:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.activemq:activemq-jdbc-store:jar:5.14.5:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.components:geronimo-connector:jar:3.1.4:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.components:geronimo-transaction:jar:3.1.4:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.objectweb.howl:howl:jar:1.0.1-1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.javamail:geronimo-javamail_1.4_mail:jar:1.9.0-alpha-2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.xbean:xbean-asm6-shaded:jar:4.9:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.xbean:xbean-finder-shaded:jar:4.9:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.xbean:xbean-reflect:jar:4.9:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.xbean:xbean-naming:jar:4.9:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.xbean:xbean-bundleutils:jar:4.9:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:2.3.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-dbcp2:jar:2.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:jar:2.3:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.openejb.shade:quartz-openejb-shade:jar:2.2.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.openwebbeans:openwebbeans-spi:jar:1.7.5:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.openwebbeans:openwebbeans-ejb:jar:1.7.5:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.openwebbeans:openwebbeans-ee:jar:1.7.5:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.openwebbeans:openwebbeans-ee-common:jar:1.7.5:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.openjpa:openjpa:jar:2.4.3:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- net.sourceforge.serp:serp:jar:1.15.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.bval:bval-core:jar:1.1.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.bval:bval-jsr:jar:1.1.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.myfaces.core:myfaces-impl:jar:2.2.12:test
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8:test
[INFO] |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.taglibs:taglibs-standard-jstlel:jar:1.2.5:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.taglibs:taglibs-standard-spec:jar:1.2.5:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.taglibs:taglibs-standard-impl:jar:1.2.5:test
[INFO] |  +- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.2:test
[INFO] |  |     \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.04:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:8.5.32:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-dbcp:jar:8.5.32:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-catalina:jar:8.5.32:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-servlet-api:jar:8.5.32:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jsp-api:jar:8.5.32:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-api:jar:8.5.32:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jni:jar:8.5.32:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-util:jar:8.5.32:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-util-scan:jar:8.5.32:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jaspic-api:jar:8.5.32:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-catalina-ha:jar:8.5.32:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-tribes:jar:8.5.32:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-coyote:jar:8.5.32:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jasper:jar:8.5.32:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-el-api:jar:8.5.32:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.jdt:ecj:jar:3.12.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jasper-el:jar:8.5.32:test
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler:ecj:jar:4.4:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.6.4:test
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomee:openejb-client:jar:7.0.5:test
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.3.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:2.3.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomee:tomee-webservices:jar:7.0.5:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomee:openejb-webservices:jar:7.0.5:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomee:openejb-cxf:jar:7.0.5:test
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-ws-security-dom:jar:2.1.9:test
[INFO] |  |     |  \- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-ws-security-common:jar:2.1.9:test
[INFO] |  |     |     +- org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:jar:2.0.8:test
[INFO] |  |     |     +- org.opensaml:opensaml-saml-impl:jar:3.1.1:test
[INFO] |  |     |     |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-profile-api:jar:3.1.1:test
[INFO] |  |     |     |  |  \- org.opensaml:opensaml-core:jar:3.1.1:test
[INFO] |  |     |     |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-saml-api:jar:3.1.1:test
[INFO] |  |     |     |  |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-xmlsec-api:jar:3.1.1:test
[INFO] |  |     |     |  |  \- org.opensaml:opensaml-soap-api:jar:3.1.1:test
[INFO] |  |     |     |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-security-impl:jar:3.1.1:test
[INFO] |  |     |     |  |  \- org.opensaml:opensaml-security-api:jar:3.1.1:test
[INFO] |  |     |     |  |     \- org.cryptacular:cryptacular:jar:1.0:test
[INFO] |  |     |     |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-xmlsec-impl:jar:3.1.1:test
[INFO] |  |     |     |  \- net.shibboleth.utilities:java-support:jar:7.1.1:test
[INFO] |  |     |     +- org.opensaml:opensaml-xacml-impl:jar:3.1.1:test
[INFO] |  |     |     |  \- org.opensaml:opensaml-xacml-api:jar:3.1.1:test
[INFO] |  |     |     +- org.opensaml:opensaml-xacml-saml-impl:jar:3.1.1:test
[INFO] |  |     |     |  \- org.opensaml:opensaml-xacml-saml-api:jar:3.1.1:test
[INFO] |  |     |     \- org.jasypt:jasypt:jar:1.9.2:test
[INFO] |  |     +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.57:test
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-policy:jar:2.1.9:test
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-ws-security-stax:jar:2.1.9:test
[INFO] |  |     |  \- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-bindings:jar:2.1.9:test
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-ws-security-policy-stax:jar:2.1.9:test
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:jar:3.2.6:test
[INFO] |  |     |  +- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] |  |     |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-soap:jar:3.2.6:test
[INFO] |  |     |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-wsdl:jar:3.2.6:test
[INFO] |  |     |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb:jar:3.2.6:test
[INFO] |  |     |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-xml:jar:3.2.6:test
[INFO] |  |     |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-simple:jar:3.2.6:test
[INFO] |  |     |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-addr:jar:3.2.6:test
[INFO] |  |     |     \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-policy:jar:3.2.6:test
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-security:jar:3.2.6:test
[INFO] |  |     |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-security-saml:jar:3.2.6:test
[INFO] |  |     \- com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj:saaj-impl:jar:1.3.23:test
[INFO] |  |        +- org.jvnet.mimepull:mimepull:jar:1.9:test
[INFO] |  |        \- org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex:jar:1.7.4:test
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-websocket:jar:8.5.32:test
[INFO] +- org.apache.tomee:tomee-jaxrs:jar:7.0.5:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomee:tomee-loader:jar:7.0.5:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:8.5.32:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomee:tomee-common:jar:7.0.5:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomee:openejb-rest:jar:7.0.5:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomee:openejb-cxf-rs:jar:7.0.5:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomee:openejb-cxf-transport:jar:7.0.5:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:jar:3.2.6:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-management:jar:3.2.6:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-rs-service-description:jar:3.1.15:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-rs-client:jar:3.2.6:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:jar:3.2.6:test
[INFO] |  |  |     \- com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:jar:5.1.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs:jar:3.2.6:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-rs-extension-search:jar:3.2.6:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-rs-security-cors:jar:3.2.6:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-rs-security-oauth2:jar:3.2.6:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-rs-security-jose-jaxrs:jar:3.2.6:test
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-security:jar:3.2.6:test
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-rs-security-jose:jar:3.2.6:test
[INFO] |  |  |        \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-rs-json-basic:jar:3.2.6:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-rs-extension-providers:jar:3.2.6:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.johnzon:johnzon-jaxrs:jar:1.0.1:test
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.johnzon:johnzon-mapper:jar:1.0.1:test
[INFO] |  |        \- org.apache.johnzon:johnzon-core:jar:1.0.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomee:openejb-server:jar:7.0.5:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomee:openejb-ejbd:jar:7.0.5:test
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tomee:openejb-http:jar:7.0.5:test
[INFO] \- com.sap.cloud:neo-javaee7-wp-api:jar:1.44.12:test
[INFO]    +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-json_1.0_spec:jar:1.0-alpha-1:test
[INFO]    +- javax.servlet.jsp:javax.servlet.jsp-api:jar:2.3.1:test
[INFO]    +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-validation_1.1_spec:jar:1.0:test
[INFO]    +- javax.mail:javax.mail-api:jar:1.5.5:test
[INFO]    +- com.sun.faces:jsf-api:jar:2.2.12:test
[INFO]    +- javax.enterprise:cdi-api:jar:1.1:test
[INFO]    +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.2_spec:jar:1.0-alpha-1:test
[INFO]    +- javax.el:javax.el-api:jar:3.0.0:test
[INFO]    +- org.apache.chemistry.opencmis:chemistry-opencmis-commons-api:jar:1.0.0:test
[INFO]    +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-annotation_1.2_spec:jar:1.0:test
[INFO]    +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jaxrs_2.0_spec:jar:1.0-alpha-1:test
[INFO]    +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jpa_2.1_spec:jar:1.0-alpha-1:test
[INFO]    +- org.apache.chemistry.opencmis:chemistry-opencmis-client-api:jar:1.0.0:test
[INFO]    +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-atinject_1.0_spec:jar:1.0:test
[INFO]    +- javax.ejb:javax.ejb-api:jar:3.2:test
[INFO]    +- javax.websocket:javax.websocket-api:jar:1.1:test
[INFO]    +- javax.servlet.jsp.jstl:jstl-api:jar:1.2:test
[INFO]    \- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:test
```

I get this [sap extensibility scenario](https://extensibilityexplorer.cfapps.eu10.hana.ondemand.com/ExtensibilityExplorer/#/ExtScenario/352), and I adapted it to my specific needs.

As there was no integration test, I took the NEO archetype as a starting point to get dependencies and write test classes [archetype SAP CP Neo + Java EE 7].

May I know how to fix this issue? or any clue that might help me move forward?

BR,
Pietro

Comment: Just because you deleted your last, similar question: please don't do that, rather edit it if possible.

Comment: Sure. I keep that in mind from now on. I am still not used to how the tool works.
I just wanted to make sure you guys are aware the issue was not happening anymore. Indeed the issue is related, but I heavy changed the POM. Before, I was using the old SDK version. Now by taking the dependencies from the archetype, I am using sap cloud SDK v3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the dependency tree, I can see that there is a mix-up of SDK dependencies of version 2 and 3 in your project which is causing the issue.

The dependency entries with groupId starting with `com.sap.cloud.s4hana` are mostly v2 dependencies and the ones with groupId starting with `com.sap.cloud.sdk` are v3 dependencies.So, please use [this](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sap/cloud/sdk/sdk-modules-bom/3.11.0/sdk-modules-bom-3.11.0.pom) as a reference to convert all v2 dependencies to the corresponding v3 dependencies.

Alternatively, you can also include the `sdk-bom` dependency (groupId: `com.sap.cloud.sdk`, artifactId: `sdk-bom` ) in your pom with a `version`, so that you can start including other sdk dependencies without explicitly including the `version` information. 
This would also ensure that all the sdk dependencies you include would always fall into the a particular version:

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sap.cloud.sdk</groupId>
      <artifactId>sdk-bom</artifactId>
      <version>3.15.1</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```